# Behat - Symfony\Dependency-Injection Issues

Tags: php, selenium, behat

I've been trying to set up Behat for a while now but nothing works. I installed Behat using composer and I've tried to initialise the behat and it keeps giving me errors like this:

```
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get<> C:\users\k\documents\test\vendor\sympfony\dependency-injection\Symfony\Component\DependencyInection\ContainerBuilder.php
```

There are hundreds of lines similar to the above error but they all have to do with dependecy inection. I can't run any feature file without getting this error.

My YML looks like this:

```
default:
paths:
features: %behat.paths.base%/feature
bootstrap: %behat.paths.base%/features/bootstrap
extensions:
Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
 goutte: ~
 selenium: ~
```

Directory:
[image]

Also, I added the bootstrap folder manually from the vendor folder because when I tried to initialise it, I was getting those errors but still no difference. I don't really know what the problem is here. Any help would be really appreciated. I've been working on this for over a day now and I have no idea why I'm getting those errors.

Comment: Path in your error message looks wrong - vendor\sympfony instead of vendor/symfony. How have you installed behat exactly? Also, YAML formatting is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your help but you said vendor/symfony instead of vendor/symfony. I don't get the difference. Also, where is wrong in the YAML? I'm new to Behat so it's hard to install and I've followed a lot of tutorials.

Comment: Read my message again. Carefully. vendor\sympfony vs vendor\symfony. Your yaml, at least the one you pasted, is not formatted properly (indentation is wrong).

Comment: oh, ok. Thanks, I'll fix it. Although, I checked and it installs Symfony on its own rather than Sympfony and the packages are vendor/symfony. I apologize if I'm mistaken about something.